# Not receiving ACTION_CAMERA_BUTTON broadcast event

Tags: android

I want to handle ACTION_CAMERA_BUTTON using broadcast receiver. I have added the following in androidmanifest file

```
<receiver android:name="MappedKeysIntentReceiver">
        <intent-filter android:priority = "999">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_CAMERA_BUTTON" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

But I dont get the broadcast on pressing the camera button, how ever if I register manually then I am receiving the event. 
Could anyone throw some light on this behavior. I want the receiver to be specified in manifest file instead of registering it manuayyly. I have tried it on lg optimus gt540 and Milestone both are running 2.1 android os.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your action name is wrong. It is `android.intent.action.CAMERA_BUTTON` when represented as a string.